# Can environment variables be exported in Azure ML Studio

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am working in `Azure ML Studio`. I have created a `jupyter notebook`. I am running a `python` code in the `notebook`. I want to provide a value to the code. Rather than hard-coding the value, I want to provide it as environment variable. How could I do this?

Eg., instead of

```
API_KEY = "somevalue"
```

I want to do

```
API_KEY = os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the python package called `python-dotenv`([python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)), which loads the variables from `.env` files and you use those as you get environment variables like `os.getenv()`.

Follow below steps,

First, create a `.env` file and add your environment values like below.

[image]

Next, upload this file into your notebook workspace.
By default, the filename starts with `.(dot)` are hidden.

[image]
Then install the `python-dotenv`  library.

```
%pip install python-dotenv
```

Load the environment variables by executing below code.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

Now, get the variables using `os.getenv()` function as below.

```
import  os
print(os.getenv("YOUR_APT_KEY"),os.getenv("YOUR_HOST"))
```

[image]

Here, you can see the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that `Azure ML Studio` workspace also has a shell. It runs `bash`. I could export the variables there and use them in notebook.

[image]